# Two regular expressions in grep with alternation

Tags: regex, linux, open-source, grep

```
'^\{[a-z]*:[0-9]*\}$|;^[a-z]=[0-9]$'
```

What's wrong? The documentation (man page) said that | is alternation operator.

Comment: You may want to tell us about the symptoms before asking what's wrong :)

Comment: Are you sure of `;^`, a semicolon in front of the begin?

Comment: what's wrong means why does not work...

Comment: according to MAN it should be |; so yes I am sure

Comment: @Gumbo `^` only has special meaning (as the start of line anchor) when it is at the start of regular expression (or immediately after the alternate/or operator `|`). `;^` would match those two characters in a string, e.g. would match the line 'text;^more stuff'

Answer (score 7):

From the man page:

> **Alternation**
>   Two regular expressions may be joined by the infix operator |; the resulting regular expression matches any string matching either alternate expression.

You are misinterpreting this, it is not saying that `|;` is the alternation operator, it is saying that `|` is the alternation operator, the semi-colon separates the two parts of the sentence.

Also, unless you are using the extended regex option (`-E`) you will need to escape the `|`:

> **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**
>   In  basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

The end result might look something like this:

```
grep -E '^\{[a-z]*:[0-9]*\}$|^[a-z]=[0-9]$' some_file
```

Or without the `-E` option:

```
grep '^{[a-z]*:[0-9]*}$\|^[a-z]=[0-9]$' some_file
```

Comment: Note: This is not part of the original question, but if alternation is only for some part of the regular expression, it can be grouped with "\\(" and "\\)". In fact, the regular expression can be refactored to eliminate some redundancy wrt. `^` and `$`: '^\\(\{[a-z]*:[0-9]*\}|[a-z]=[0-9]\\)$' (leaving out the semicolon mistake). It is not much in this case, but it can be massive for other regular expressions.